# Openlaszlo dhtml debugging

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

Is it possible to debug the application in dhtml runtime. I installed the firebug and then i gave debug = true and i started my application. But i got an error
**$reportException is not defined** and later i figured out that i haven't included the LFCdhtml-debug.js.

After including the js the debug window appeared but the window is not draggable and the window looks distorted any idea why do i need to include any more resources?

Comment: I never had problems debugging DHTML apps with Firebug or in Chrome.  How do you embed the application into the HTML page? Do you use the deployment target "lzt=html"? The error message you are seeing might be related to Firefox add-on you have installed. Try to disable all add-ons but Firebug, or use the safe mode of Firefox  
http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode

Comment: OpenLaszlo docs: "If you set logdebug to true, then any output to the debugger will be logged. This can be helpful if you find the system crashing before the debugger is started. We recommend using the console debugger first and only resort to logging if even the console debugger is not working. (For the DHTML runtimes, if there is a runtime console object with a log method, logging will be automatically turned on. This is the case for Safari if the Developer feature is enabled, or Firefox if the Firebug plug-in is installed.)"  
http://www.openlaszlo.org/lps4.9/docs/developers/debugging.html